# Set aspxauth cookie unchangeable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

How do i set aspxauth unchangeable, like for instance the client/user change its value then after proceeding to other pages the original aspxauth value will remain and not be signout.

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Sorry for that, i just want my aspxauth not to be modified. Just when the user modified the aspxauth value and then you hit refresh the original aspxauth value should remain

Comment: That's not really possible. There are any number of ways the value might be changed, including via proxy.

Comment: @erik how about storing the aspxauth value upon first authentication in a session container then every request will check if the aspxauth was change and if its true from modification the server will assign back the first aspxauth value

Answer (score 1):

*ASPXAuth Cookie* stores in client browser (location of cookie path might be different, depends on browser) and it is impossible to avoid changing it from server. Besides, if AspxAuth cookie has been changed, the server redirects the client to login page. Because, the server decrypts auth cookie and extracts several data like *Name, Expiration, IsPersistent etc*. It determines that the user can remain in authentication or not. So if the cookie has been changed, authentication can't be performed no longer from server side.

Comment: Hi @rainman thank you for your answer, i need to set back its original value on server side once modified before checking of authentication, as you said that it can be modified on browser, but i think not on server.